# Why sometimes the nuget packages fail after merging in git

Tags: git, nuget, git-merge, solution, nuget-package-restore

I had a problem about nuget packages sometimes when i merge two branches in git.
I search and found which the problem is about solution user options(.suo) file, then after removing it and restarting the visual studio, all the errors gone. 
Why this happen? what can I do to avoid it? I know that .suo file should't checked in source control and check my git repository for it, nothing found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be safe, make sure that your `.gitattributes` file includes a newline with `*.suo binary` so that git does not try to merge them. Otherwise, git will try to merge the `.gitattributes` from both branches and create errors.

Also make sure to put `*.suo` in your project's `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks. but i can't find any .gitattributes   or .gitignore file.

Comment: You may have _file name extensions_ hidden in Windows. This would hide those files from you. Which version of Windows are you using? If it's 10, simply navigate to your project directory in the File Explorer, click the **View** tab, and make sure the `File name extensions` checkbox is checked.

Comment: I searched the hidden files and it just found the gitignore file and also it's already had *.suo in it.

Comment: If `.gitattributes` does not exist, you can still create it in your project's root directory and edit it to make sure it includes one line containing  `*.suo binary`. To see an example of what a typical `.gitattributes` file looks like for C#, check out mine from one of my own C# MVC projects [here](pastebin.com/QdK4CjZh).